# Using a variable to define other variable before taking it as input

Tags: c++, variables, infinite-loop

In the below code I defined both n and k initially and then if I define n as k/2 after I take k as input using cin, the code is successful but instead of this if I define n=k/2 before cin function I get an infinite loop as output? Please tell why is defining below or after cin function is affecting the output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
cout<< "how many asterisks you want in the middle column:";
int n,k;
// n=k/2 ; 
cin>>k;
// n=k/2;

//some code involving n
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of statements makes a difference:

```cpp
int k = 2;
int n = k/2;
k = 4;
```

is different than

```cpp
int k = 2;
k = 4;
int n = k/2;
```

In the first case, you get `n = 1`, and in the second `n = 2`. This *really* shouldn't surprise you! You might need to revise your programming basics before dealing with loops if it does :)

Other things:

- never use `using namespace std;`. Not doing that, but specifically only importing the things you need will save you a **lot** of time later on, debugging very strange problems (I don't know why this is still taught): `using std::cin;`, `using std::cout;` is maybe longer, but much better, because you know what you get in your name space!
- Properly indent your code. Yes, your editor has a function for that, and if it hasn't, get a better editor (these things *really* make a difference, especially for a beginner, because they help you spot little typos much easier!). Many beginners like Code::blocks as editor, because it's easy to set up and good, others like the more mightier VS Code.

Comment: In the example given by you the order matters but I have not given any value to k initially just defined as integer and then stated n as k/2 followed by k's value from user in which I get an infinite loop, so shouldn't the order be of no use and give same result here?

Comment: no, it should not. The fact that you didn't explicitly give it a value doesn't change the semantics! Every line gets executed, on its own. `n = k/2` doesn't say "`n` will change its value when `k` changes"; it says "`n` gets the value `k/2` based on the *current* value of `k`", nothing else! As said, you really might need to go back to basics for a moment here.

Comment: Yeah as Marcus said the order always matters and so you're saying n is equal to k/2 when k doesn't have a value(yet) I guess you think c++ can just see that you're gonna give k a value later but that's not how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I got it now.